# Lucene 3.6 Index File Optimisation after Backup Restore

Tags: java, lucene

I am using lucene 3.6 as a search engine for a java desktop application.
 A directory file to used to store the lucene index.

The application has a backup operation that backs up the database.
 The question is that when the backup database is restored, how do I optimize the 
 lucene index directory to reflect the new database and not the old database.

For example :

Index File A contains index for database A.

Database B is restored into the system. Current database is B. 
 How do I make index file store index for database B and not A.

Do I have to rebuild the index (undesirable if the database is large) , 
or is there another way out.

best regards ,

CodeAngel

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain multiple indexes as well, swapping over to a saved index maintined with Database B at the same time that you swap to Database B.  For backups, it would likely help to create a snapshot of your index, using a [PersistentSnapshotDeletionPolicy](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_2_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/PersistentSnapshotDeletionPolicy.html).  Whether that suits your backup strategy is up to you to determine.

Either that, or rebuild the index.

Comment: I think the safest option is to rebuild the whole index. Despite that it might take a longer time that copying and restoring a SNAP-SHOT of the index.

Comment: Yes, rebuilding will definitely take longer than opening a reader on an existing index.  On safety, maintaining a snapshot of the index isn't inherently unsafe.  That would depend on your implementation.